How to do a continous trajectory in Staubli VAL 3
I am doing a trajectory passing from 6 points with these command in VAL 3:

  for m=0 to 6 step 1
    movej(p_iman[m],tTool1,mNomSpeed)
    waitEndMove()
  endFor


I want to do a continuos trajectory, without stopping in each point. What function should I use?
